# Power BI / Google Analytics Connector API Error

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi, google-analytics-api, powerbi-datasource

I am using the Google Analytics connector in Power BI to pull the current day's order, user and sessions data, grouped by hour, into our model.  This is done every fifteen minutes.

I've used the connector since November without an issue.  However, recently I'm getting the following error.
"GoogleAnalytics: Request failed (403): Quota Error: Number of recent failed reporting API requests is too high, please implement exponential back off.  See developer documentation for details at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors."

The error occurs sporadically.  It can be a problem for days, and then disappear.  It can show up for an hour, then go away.

I've opened a ticket with Microsoft Power BI support.  After investigating they had no explanation and asked that I open a ticket with GA support.

Can somebody please help point me in the right direction as to how to resolve this?

Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running into the quotas for the reporting API. The limits are quite high so hard to hit usually.

I'd investigate in the following order.

1. Are there are other users doing similar requests for similar data?
2. How many and how long are the requests used via bower bi. Might be one report but multiple requests which take longer to complete.
3. What other way are others using the API. Do you populate a database with GA data in a batch wise fashion. If so is it possible to do this at a time when others don't need the resource?

The limits in link give a good idea of what can happen if there are many users using the same profile.

> 10 concurrent requests per view (profile) (cannot be increased)

The specific error you are getting is due to number of failed requests. This could be because the requests themselves are bad or that they are bad because they violate the quota. I'd expect the latter if this worked previously. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

So Power bi's connector for google analytics has a sampling issue and an API Calls limit.
The standard limitations and quotas for Google Analytics API requests are documented in Limits and Quotas on API Requests. However, Power BI Desktop and Power BI service allow you to use the following enhanced number of queries.

Queries per day: 1,500,000
Queries per 100 seconds: 4,000

Might be better to connect Google analytics to a data warehouse such as Google BigQuery, which will help you get access to historical data that you won't be able to get with Power bi's connector.
I'd suggest using a third-party connector.